# How can I forward client cert CN from Apache web server?

Tags: apache, ssl, client-certificates

I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy to redirect all requests. I need to forward client cert details to my apps within the request. For testing purposes, I'm simply trying to attach CN to the forwarded request. This is my `conf` file (simplified):

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile     /etc/ssl/certs/CA.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/ssl/private/CA.key

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth  1

    SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8443/myapp?cn=%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}
</VirtualHost>
```

If I navigate to `https://localhost` browser asks for a cert, and then I get redirected to:

```
https://localhost:8443/myapp?cn=
```

So it appears that it's not reading `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN`. What am I missing?

EDIT: If I set request header, e.g.:

```
RequestHeader set XYZ %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}e
```

I don't see it in dev tools, either. So there must be something wrong with my configuration. `%{SERVER_NAME}` works, `%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}` doesn't.

Comment: It's usually forwarded in a header, not via the URL.

Comment: @EJP yes, but should i not be able to see it in the URL?

Comment: Why, if it's in a header? Get it working the right way. This is the wrong way.

Comment: @EJP i can't get it to work in a header either, see my edit.

Comment: You have to set it in the response header, if you want to see something.

Comment: Have you tried %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}?